# What is a single word for being sweet but sarcastic?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, abbreviations

A word which could stand for being "***sweet but could be sassy***". Especially about girls. An adjective which could mean that the person is sweet normally but could be impulsive or sarcastic.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 2):

**Cheeky** is the word.

> boldly rude, impudent, or disrespectful in usually a playful or appealing way

*a cheeky grin*

*… old-timers who still look like they could deck you if you get too cheeky.*
— Shaun Assael

[Merriam-Webster]

> If you describe a person or their behaviour as cheeky, you think that they are slightly rude or disrespectful but in a charming or amusing way.
> [mainly British]

*The boy was cheeky and casual.*

*Martin gave her a cheeky grin.*

[Collins]

Answer (score 1):

As your word applies especially to a girl, you could sometimes use **pert**

> Pert
>
> used to describe behaviour or qualities, especially in a young woman, that are humorous because they do not show much respect
>
> (esp. of a young woman) energetic, enthusiastic, and confident
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pert)